# Unable to export Eclipse RCP application as a product

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, product

I have an application which I want to export as a product. For that purpose I have create a product for my RCP application. While creating the product definition, I have chose the Application as EditorApp.application. Added EditorApp(My application) as dependency and added also the required plug ins. Also under the configuration tab, I have added the recommended start levels for the plugins.

The product is exporting. But while I am trying to run the product, it gives the following error:

```
    !SESSION 2016-01-26 15:56:56.353 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_45
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-01-26 15:56:57.897
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in EditorApp was unable to load class com.app.application.Application.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.app.application.Application cannot be found by EditorApp_1.0.0.201601261556
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    ... 15 more
```

Please note, 
1. This application is running properly when I am running this from Eclipse.
2. I have Application.java file present in my project. But, I have kept it inside the package - com.app.application. The code for Application.java looks like this:

```java
package com.app.application;

import org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication;
import org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplicationContext;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbench;
import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;

import com.app.editor.ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor;

/**
 * This class controls all aspects of the application's execution.
 */
public class Application implements IApplication {

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication#start(org.eclipse.equinox.app.
     * IApplicationContext)
     */
    public Object start(IApplicationContext context) throws Exception {
        Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay();
        try {
            int returnCode = PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(display,
                    new ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor());
            if (returnCode == PlatformUI.RETURN_RESTART) {
                return IApplication.EXIT_RESTART;
            } else {
                return IApplication.EXIT_OK;
            }
        } finally {
            display.dispose();
        }

    }
```

Please suggest.

Thanks!

Update:

MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: EditorApp
Bundle-SymbolicName: EditorApp;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Vendor: APP
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 library/log4j-1.2.17.jar,
 library/mariadb-java-client-1.2.3.jar
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 com.ibm.icu,
 org.eclipse.jface.databinding,
 org.eclipse.core.databinding.property,
 org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable,
 org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans,
 org.eclipse.core.databinding,
 org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.9.1"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Export-Package: com.app.editor;
  uses:="org.osgi.framework,
   org.eclipse.ui,
   org.eclipse.jface.action,
   org.eclipse.equinox.app,
   org.eclipse.jface.resource,
   org.eclipse.ui.application,
   org.eclipse.ui.plugin",
 com.app.editor.actions;uses:="org.eclipse.jface.action",
 com.app.editor.beans,
 com.app.editor.functionalities;
  uses:="org.eclipse.swt.graphics,
   org.eclipse.swt.widgets,
   org.eclipse.jface.dialogs,
   javax.swing.tree",
 com.app.editor.handlers;uses:="org.eclipse.core.commands",
 com.app.editor.perspectives;uses:="org.eclipse.ui",
 com.app.editor.views;
  uses:="com.app.editor.beans,
   org.eclipse.swt.widgets,
   org.eclipse.swt.custom,
   com.app.editor.functionalities,
   org.eclipse.core.databinding,
   org.eclipse.jface.viewers,
   org.eclipse.ui.part"
```

Plugin.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         id="application"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications">
      <application>
         <run
               class="com.app.application.Application">
         </run>
      </application>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectives">
      <perspective
            name="RCP Perspective"
            class="com.app.editor.perspectives.Perspective"
            id="com.app.Editor.perspective">
      </perspective>
      <perspective
            class="com.app.editor.perspectives.NewFilePerspective"
            id="com.app.Editor.newFileperspective"
            name="New File Prespective">
      </perspective>
      <perspective
            class="com.app.editor.perspectives.OpenFilePerspective"
            id="com.app.Editor.openFileperspective"
            name="Open File Perspective">
      </perspective>
      <perspective
            class="com.app.editor.perspectives.CloseViewPerspective"
            id="com.app.Editor.closeViewperspective"
            name="Close View Prespective">
      </perspective>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            defaultHandler="com.app.editor.handlers.NewFileHandler"
            id="com.app.Editor.New"
            name="New">
      </command>
      <command
            defaultHandler="com.app.editor.handlers.OpenHandler"
            id="com.app.Editor.Open"
            name="Connect To Database">
      </command>
      <command
            defaultHandler="com.app.editor.handlers.ExitHandler"
            id="com.app.Editor.commands.Exit"
            name="Exit">
      </command>
      <command
            defaultHandler="com.app.editor.handlers.CloseHandler"
            id="com.app.Editor.close"
            name="Close">
      </command>
      <command
            defaultHandler="com.app.editor.handlers.AboutHandler"
            description="About"
            id="com.app.Editor.about"
            name="About">
      </command>
      <command
            defaultHandler="com.app.editor.handlers.SaveHandler"
            id="com.app.Editor.Save"
            name="Save">
      </command>
      <command
            defaultHandler="com.app.editor.handlers.SaveAsHandler"
            id="com.app.Editor.SaveAs"
            name="Save As..">
      </command>
      <command
            defaultHandler="com.app.editor.handlers.RestartHandler"
            id="com.app.Editor.Restart"
            name="Restart">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">
         <menu
               id="fileMenu"
               label="File">
            <command
                  commandId="com.app.Editor.New"
                  label="New"
                  style="push">
            </command>
            <command
                  commandId="com.app.Editor.Open"
                  label="Connect To Database"
                  style="push">
            </command>
            <command
                  commandId="com.app.Editor.Save"
                  label="Save"
                  style="push">
            </command>
            <command
                  commandId="com.app.Editor.close"
                  label="Close"
                  style="push">
            </command>
            <command
                  commandId="com.app.Editor.Restart"
                  label="Restart"
                  style="push">
            </command>
            <command
                  commandId="com.app.Editor.commands.Exit"
                  label="Exit"
                  style="push">
            </command>
         </menu>
         <menu
               id="helpMenu"
               label="Help">
            <command
                  commandId="com.app.Editor.about"
                  label="About"
                  style="push">
            </command>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
      <view
            class="com.app.editor.views.OpenView"
            id="com.app.Editor.openView"
            name="OpenView"
            restorable="true">
      </view>
      <view
            class="com.app.editor.views.CloseView"
            id="com.app.Editor.closeView"
            name="CloseView"
            restorable="true">
      </view>
      <view
            allowMultiple="false"
            class="com.app.editor.views.NewView"
            id="com.app.Editor.newView"
            name="NewView"
            restorable="true">
      </view>
      <view
            class="com.app.editor.views.TreeView"
            id="com.app.Editor.treeView"
            name="TreeView"
            restorable="true">
      </view>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
   </extension>
   <extension
         id="product"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
      <product
            application="EditorApp.application"
            name="Tree Editor">
         <property
               name="appName"
               value="Tree Editor">
         </property>
      </product>
   </extension>
   <extension
         id="product1"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
      <product
            application="EditorApp.application"
            name="Tree Editor">
         <property
               name="appName"
               value="Tree Editor">
         </property>
      </product>
   </extension>
   <extension
         id="product2"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
      <product
            application="EditorApp.application"
            name="Tree Editor">
         <property
               name="appName"
               value="Tree Editor">
         </property>
      </product>
   </extension>
   <extension
         id="product3"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
      <product
            application="EditorApp.application"
            name="Tree Editor">
         <property
               name="appName"
               value="Tree Editor">
         </property>
      </product>
   </extension>
   <extension
         id="product4"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
      <product
            application="EditorApp.application"
            name="Tree Editor">
      </product>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

build.properties

```
     output.. = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
               .,\
               META-INF/,\
               library/log4j-1.2.17.jar,\
               library/mariadb-java-client-1.2.3.jar
```

Update: Changed the code above and I have now removed the jar file from classpath. Now, the application is  running, but while accessing the jar (fr example database connection) it breaks.

Comment: Your Application class is not being found. Show us the MANIFEST.MF, plugin.xml and build.properties for the plugin

Comment: Sure.. Thanks Greg...

Comment: @greg-449 .. updated he question. Added the needed information. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `build.properties` file is not including the class files in the built plugin. You must include `.` in the `bin.includes` list:

```
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
               .,\
               META-INF/,\
               library/
```

If you are using additional jars you should add them to the plugin (using Jars external to the RCP is very tricky).

So for example:

```
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               plugin.properties,\
               plugin.xml,\
               lib/jogg-0.0.7.jar,\
               lib/jorbis-0.0.15.jar,\
               lib/vorbisspi1.0.2.jar
```

Here I have three jars in the 'lib' directory of my plugin.

The 'Build' tab of the plugin.xml/MANIFEST.MF editor lets you specify this.

You must also include the jars in the `Bundle-Classpath' header in the MANIFEST.MF. So for my example:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 lib/jogg-0.0.7.jar,
 lib/jorbis-0.0.15.jar,
 lib/vorbisspi1.0.2.jar
```

Note: The `.` entry must also be specified to include the main plugin code.

You can specify this using the 'Classpath' section of the 'Runtime' tab of the plugin.xml/MANIFEST.MF editor.

Comment: Oh okay.. I am editing that now and will post the result. Thanks again @greg-449

Comment: Thanks @greg-449 ... for the suggestion. But, still, it is giving the same error.

Comment: Also, in Configuration tab of the product file, do I need to add the plugin(which  I have created) in the start levels tab?

Comment: You don't usually need anything in the start levels and getting them wrong can cause issues.

Comment: Okay, then I will remove and try again! Tried but not working

Comment: One more thing, I have used 2 external jar files, But I have mentioned them in build,properties. (updated above). Can this cause this issue?

Comment: Libraries must be in a plugin and the build.properties must specify the relative path of each library to be included. The MANIFEST.MF must include them in the Bundle-Classpath.

Comment: Can you please explain a little? I created a plugin (RCP application) EditorApp which used 2 external plugins. So I downloaded the jars and added them in the classpath. Added them in build.properties. Instead what should I do?

Comment: what I tried was, I created a plugin with 2 jar files which I used for my application. Then, I created a jar file of it and added that jar file in the classpath. Is that what you said?

Comment: Never just set the Java classpath, that won't work on the exported RCP. I have added some more to the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101689/discussion-between-javaprogrammer-and-greg-449).

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to open chat from office. But, I have done the changes suggested. I am updating the code fragment above. But, still same issue is coming

Comment: Updated the code and the issue now! Thanks again for your effort... Please help!

Comment: Changed the code above and I have now removed the jar file from classpath. Now, the application is running, but while accessing the jar (fr example database connection) it breaks.